# No name 'xml' in module 'py'

Tags: python, pylint

Unfortunately, I have to use `pipenv` (not my decision), and Python 3 (again, not my decision) in a project that needs to use `py.xml` package.  And it also needs to pass `pylint` verification.

One of the files in this project has this:

```
from py.xml import html
```

Even though `py` is installed in virtual environment, `pylint` cannot find it, while it... can find it.  This seems more like a problem with `pylint`, but maybe not.  I have no idea how to debug this mess.  Below is the proof of `pylint` split personality:

```
PYTHONPATH=$(pwd) pipenv run pylint --init-hook 'from py.xml import html;print(type(html))' some_module
<class 'py._xmlgen.NamespaceMetaclass'>
************* Module some_module
E:  8, 0: No name 'xml' in module 'py' (no-name-in-module)
E:  8, 0: Unable to import 'py.xml' (import-error)
```

Not sure if I get any bonus karma points for the irony in the line above, but if you are new to the concepts of virtualization, I might just put a little note here:

> It makes no sense to specify PYTHONPATH when running a program which is supposed to set up your virtual environment, yet, for all the loads of nonsense code it contains, the only thing it was supposed to do, it doesn't.  Doesn't even try, actually.

---

Oh, and in case you thought that `py` may have been installed somewhere else, and somehow was not accessible to `pylint`... well, it wasn't:

```
PYTHONPATH=$(pwd) pipenv run pylint --init-hook 'from py.xml import html;import inspect;print(inspect.getfile(html))' automation
/home/wvxvw/.local/share/virtualenvs/some_module-UoeXL6dQ/lib/python3.5/site-packages/py/_xmlgen.py
************* Module automation.conftest
E:  8, 0: No name 'xml' in module 'py' (no-name-in-module)
E:  8, 0: Unable to import 'py.xml' (import-error)
```

Answer (score 2):

To judge from the [source](https://github.com/pytest-dev/py/blob/master/py/__init__.py), attributes in the `py` namespace are dynamically created, and this is why pylint, a static analysis tool, is unable to recognise them:

```
apipkg.initpkg(__name__, attr={'_apipkg': apipkg}, exportdefs={
    ...
    # small and mean xml/html generation
    'xml' : {
        '__doc__'            : '._xmlgen:__doc__',
        'html'               : '._xmlgen:html',
        'Tag'                : '._xmlgen:Tag',
        'raw'                : '._xmlgen:raw',
        'Namespace'          : '._xmlgen:Namespace',
        'escape'             : '._xmlgen:escape',
    },
})
```

If pylint compliance is a requirement for your project then you will need to get agreement that warnings for these imports can be ignored.